# Problem with query on the database with save method

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a strange problem never seen before Laravel 9. Why will it add data in the **UserID** column instead of the `user_id`?

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UserId' in
> 'field list'
> insert into `translation_jobs` (`UserId`, `JobName`, `TranslFile`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, lalla,
> import/orNm2yVkussVFZqoG1NIyJZacnrofAfhymFFzWYs.xlsx, 2022-03-11
> 09:32:18, 2022-03-11 09:32:18)

**Model**

```
class TranslationJobs extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'UserId',
        'JobName',
        'FileName',
        'DocumentType',
        'RefLang',
        'TranslLanguages',
        'TranslNumber',
        'TranslDone',
        ];
}
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('translation_jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('job_name');
        $table->string('file_name');
        $table->integer('document_type')->nullable();
        $table->string('ref_lang')->nullable();
        $table->string('transl_languages')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('transl_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('transl_done')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Controller** I create a new object, and saving it:

```
$NewTranslationJob = new TranslationJobs();
$NewTranslationJob->UserID = auth()->id();
$NewTranslationJob->JobName = $request->name;
$NewTranslationJob->FileName = $ImportedFile;
$NewTranslationJob->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should be like this

```
class TranslationJobs extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id']; // removed fillable
}
```

You should use your migration column names inside your model. Not UserId but user_id

Comment: mmmh, yes, i didn't copy the guarder area, what I don't understand is why I have a app with laravel 8 that works using camelcase attribute and put data in snake case data...

Comment: You don't need to write fillable inverse is guarded. You can use one of them. If you put column name inside guarder array it won't be "fillable". Please mark is an answer if my answer is correct.

Comment: In this way it work, but I don't understand why in Laravel 8 this thing work and now don't...